# Can't create a new filter in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to add a filter to my Google Analytics data. On the administration page for a property, I click on **Filters** but get a blank view with the message:

> There is no data for this view.

Which is fine, I think, because I haven't made any filters yet. However, I see no way to create a filter on this page either. What am I missing?

Comment: Filters require edit permissions at the Account level of your GA account. Check to see that you have at least that.

Comment: No problem, answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to add/edit GA filters, you need to have the at least Edit level permissions at the Account level, because filters are an Account level property.